# FullCalendar: Drop an event but can't update this event

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, fullcalendar

I implemented the FullCalendar from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ with ColdFusion. I drop the events from outside to the calendar. This is working well, but i can't update the Event with

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', responseText.NewID);
```

I need to do this, that I can put the new ID from dem Database on the Event, for other actions like Resize, Drop to other Day or to Delete it.

I could do a Reload from the whole site, but it's not really userfriendly, because the month would be the actually month and not the month I selected before.

My Code looks like this:

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    var formdata = "startdatum="+copiedEventObject.start;

    $.ajax({
     url: '<cfoutput>#application.TartalomURL#</cfoutput>mod_Kalender/act_event_ins.cfm',
     data: formdata,
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     cache: false,
     success: function(responseText){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', responseText.NewID);
     }
      }); 
},
```

Does anyone has an idea what I'm programming wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error that you can post here?

Comment: If you are using console, add console.log(responseText) and see what comes back

Comment: My guess is that NewID may be in uppercase.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I dropped the event from outside and resized de event or drop the event to an other date. Then I get the error "The value specified, undefined, must be a valid integer." from coldfusion, because there is no ID to update this event. When I reload the site I works. 
I'm getting from responseText.newid an integer back, and that's right.
I think the problem could be that UpdateEvent don't know on which event he had to the newID. Because when I load the new site, there are all events loaded.

Comment: this is the console.log(responseText) I'm getting back: {"newid":45}

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the fullcalendar documentation:
[arshaw fullcalendar updateEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/updateEvent/)

You need the event for using the updateEvent method i.e.:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '<cfoutput>#application.TartalomURL#</cfoutput>mod_Kalender/act_event_ins.cfm',
    data: formdata,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(responseText){
        originalEvent.id = responseText.newid; //use the originating event object and update it
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', originalEvent);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like the issue. Though, the upper-case NewID may still cause an issue.

Answer (score 2):

As JavaScript is case-sensitive, should this line:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', responseText.NewID)
```

be

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', responseText.newid)
```